# Disabling italic in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

Using the tinymce wsywig editor, is there any way to disable the fact that using *text* will be italic automatically ?

Thanks in advance and regards,
Ofer

Answer (score 0):

to clarify what's happened, are you setting some content in the editor to appear when it loads? If so, you can control how content is styled when the editor loads with the setup function. Add something like this to the TinyMCE.init script:

```
setup: function (noItalic) {
  NoItalic.on('init', function () {
  this.setContent('<p>This text is not italic</p>');
  });
}
```

It might be that you have a custom style set up that puts italic tags on everything automatically.

Check your tinymce.init script for a `content_style` value and see if the font-style is set to italic;. If so, remove the font-style option or set to normal.

If neither of these fit your situation, please post some more details – how you've configured TinyMCE with a code sample so we can see the text content in italics.